# Swift struct property access

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

Could you tell me why I can not replace magic number with structs property? `self.buttonSize` does not work

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonSize = 80

    var body: some View {


        VStack {
            Button(action: {
            }) {

                Text("Hello world")
                    .frame(width: self.buttonSize, height: 80)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work, do you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is declare `buttonSize` as `CGFloat`, since that's the expected type for `width`.

```
@State var buttonSize: CGFloat = 80
```

Comment: Why sometimes I need to define data type but sometimes not?

Comment: @user2641891 Swift uses type inference, so the compiler will always try to infer the type of a variable. If the compiler cannot do that by itself due to some misambiguity or when you are working with numeric literals, if you want to change inferred type, you have to type annotate the variable. The compiler infers all integer literals to `Int`, so `var buttonSize = 80` will be of type `Int` without type annotation. However, if you type annotate `buttonSize` as `CGFloat`, it will be of type `CGFloat`, since the compiler can simply pass the `Int` to a `CGFloat` initialiser

Comment: Thanks for help, would you say the best practice is to type hint it?

Comment: @user2641891 no. Let the compiler do its job and don't create unnecessary noise with unnecessary type annotations in your code. Only use type annotation when necessary.